How to emit and listen to value from one Component to another Component in livewire?
Hello guys I am new to livewire and I am trying to send $this->wil from FormElements.php Component to form.php Component and render it on the balde file.
This Is my FormElements.php code:
class FormElements extends Component
{

    public $deliveryFees = 0;
    public $wil = 'Blida';
    public $fees = [];
    
    public function deliveryFees()
    {
        $this->deliveryFees;
        //dd($this->deliveryFees);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $destination = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('*')->pluck('destination');
        return view('livewire.form-elements', compact('destination'));
    }

    public function updatedWil()
    {
        $this->fees = DeliveryFee::select('stopdesk', 'domicile','id')
            ->where('destination', $this->wil)
            ->get()->toJson();
        $fees = ($this->fees);
        return view('livewire.form-elements', ['json' => $fees]);
    }
}

$this->wil is a dynamic value changes when an option value is selected from this code below:
<select id="wilaya" wire:model="wil"
   class="w-full dropdown-toggle  items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
      bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300"
        onchange="closeFunction()">
          @foreach ($destination as $items)
             <option value="{{ $items }}">{{ $items }}</option>
          @endforeach
     <input type="hidden" name="wilaya" value="{{ $wil }}">
 </select>

In the Other hand I have Form.php Component:
 public function render()
    {
        $wilayas = Wilaya::where('nom','Alger')->first();

        dd($wilayas->id);

        if (!empty($wilayas)) {
            
            $communes = Commune::where('wilaya_id',$wilayas->id)->get();
        }else{
            $communes = [];
        }
        return view('livewire.form',compact('wilayas' , 'communes'));
    }

I want to listen to the value sent and put it on this line of code
$wilayas = Wilaya::where('nom',$this->wil)->first(); so I can fetch the nom based on the value of $this->wil.
I hope my question is clear Please feel free to let me know the simple way to achive my idea.
Thanks in advance .

The question is not very clear... Are the two components at the same level or are they a parent and a child? In the case of the second option, how is the child included in the parent? You should post the relevant code (classes and views) for both components. Note that returning a view with a method other than render() may not work.

They're different from each other

This doesn't answer my questions. Does "different" mean two components on the same level on the same page or what else?

it is  two components on the same leve but not on the same page !!

From your description this doesn't seem possible, events can only be exchanged between components present on the same page. Laravel's (not Livewire's) event system can perhaps be used but you haven't provided enough information to formulate an answer.

what information you need I might provide ?.

I advise you to edit your question and describe better your scenario
